# Can't figure out this MySQL syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

**here is the error**

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order ASC LIMIT 100' at line 1.

**here is the query passed to PDO for a prepared execute**

`SELECT * FROM web_menu_items WHERE menuId = ? ORDER BY order ASC LIMIT 100`

**here are the variables passed to the prepared execute**

`array(0 => "1")`

**here is the table structure**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `web_menu_items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `menuId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `requiredAccess` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hideIfNotAccess` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `label` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `link` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `tagId` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `menuId` (`menuId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

what am I not seeing here? why is this a syntax error?

Comment: Isn't `order` a reserved keyword in MySQL?

Comment: Either rename 'order' column or wrap it in backticks.

Comment: You should avoid displaying mysql errors on your website.

Comment: @eversor only when it's gone live. in production, error display is quite helpful

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`order` is a reserved word in mySQL.

Put backticks around it:

```
ORDER BY `order` ASC LIMIT 100
```

or consider renaming the field.

Comment: You may want to consider renaming your column if possible to avoid such collisions. Otherwise you and others may run into this issue again in the future.

Comment: heh, of course. new it was something simple. will rename. thanks.